# Ebay Custom Listing Template

Tags: php, ebay-api

How do you go about making a custom listing template for eBay? I've seen that you can obviously add HTML to the main description area in the listing maker, but I've seen shop and listing templates which are professionally done with custom JavaScript in them.

Are they calling PHP/ASP script from another server to generate the page, and using the eBay API to grab data for the listing? So in the listing HTML description of the item, you put a line in like www.domain.com/listingtemplate.php - and it goes off and renders the code into the iframe?

Am I on the right track there?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the store designers create a script from where you create your listing but you must still just put the HTML into the description when listing the item. I haven't seen any that get data from an asp or php page. If they do its against the rules of ebay. I have seen some where they use javascript hack to get around importing external javascript files. From here you could build function which could grab data from an external host.